# Configure Gradle Kotlin DSL to work with custom repository

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm working on a project where, instead of using the default repositories (Maven Central, jCenter, and so), we are using an internal JFrog repository. The project is using Kotlin DSL for Gradle.

The problem is, even configuring the `pluginManagement` block inside the `settings.gradle.kts` file, Gradle still tries to fetch dependencies from Gradle Central Plugin Repository

```
// settings.gradle.kts
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven(url = "https://myinternalrepo.corp/artifactory")
    }
}

// other definitions
```

Failing message:

```
Plugin [id: 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl', version: '1.1.3'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl:org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl.gradle.plugin:1.1.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I haven't used Gradle with Kotlin, however I am pretty confident this ought to go in your build.gradle file. (Not sure enough to turn this into an answer yet)

Comment: Which syntax are you using to declare plugins in your build script:   new `plugins { }` DSL or the old `apply plugin ...` DSL?

Comment: Inside the project, I have a `buildSrc/build.gradle.kts` file with the kotlin-dsl plugin applied: `plugins { \`kotlin-dsl\` }`

Comment: I think  you need to create a `settings.gradle.kts` in the `buildsrc` directory, and add the `pluginManagement  { } ` block there.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Ah, yeah! This did the trick! Please add it as an answer :)

Comment: I added an aswer, hope it's clear enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to configure the plugin repositories for your `buildSrc` script, you need to create a dedicated `settings.gradle[.kts]` file inside the `buildSrc` directory and configure the `pluginManagement {}` block there.

Indeed, `buildSrc` is a kind of separate build , which is executed first , before the main build is evaluated/executed. So you cannot configure the `pluginManagement 
 {}` block in the root project's `settings.gradle` if you want to use these custom repositories in the `buildSrc` script.

Comment: I love you. You helped me soo much. Over 1 week of brainstorming why it was not working...

Comment: Thank you! I have been struggling with this problem for the last few days.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you miss Gradle Plugin Repository maven repository in your corporate cache. Just make sure you have the `https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/` included. 
The error shows exactly that it failed to find the plugin

Gradle plugins are normally listed there and the plugin dependencies are fetched from `jcenter`

BTW. We have Kotlin `1.3.20` today, maybe it makes sense to upgrade

Comment: `1.1.3` is the version of Kotlin Gradle DSL (bundled with Gradle 5.2)